# A holomorphic bijection from the open unit disc to the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

By Liouville's theorem, there is no non-constant holomorphic function from the complex plane to the unit disc. I wonder what the converse is like--surely there are holomorphic functions on the open unit disc into the complex plane, but are there any bijective ones?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You know that there are no holomorphic bijections from $\mathbb C$ onto a disk, but you ask if there are holomorphic bijections from a disk onto $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @5PM The OP just forgot that holomorphic + bijective implies that the inverse is automatically holomorphic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally: there is a holomorphic bijection from the open unit disk onto a region $U$ if and only if $U$ is simply connected and the complement of $U$ (in the Riemann sphere) has at least two points.

Comment: For reference this is The Riemann Mapping theorem which may be stated as $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is open and simply connected implies that $U$ is biholomorphic to the unit disc.

Comment: @AlexYoucis That should be $U\subsetneq\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 5):

A bijective holomorphic function has a holomorphic inverse, so certainly there are no bijective holomorphic functions from $\mathbb D$ to $\mathbb C$.

For an example of a function form $\mathbb D$ to $\mathbb C$ that's unbounded, consider $\frac{1}{1-x}$ or $e^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$.