# Is there a holomorphic bijection from the left-hand side of the complex plane to the unit disk with this property?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

I am trying to find a complex mapping from the left-hand side of the plane to the unit disk, such that
$$\lvert z_1\rvert\gt\lvert z_2\rvert\iff \lvert f(z_1)\rvert\gt\lvert f(z_2)\rvert$$
I wasn't sure what to call this property, so the title is a bit weird. According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/297673/301977)

> there is a holomorphic bijection from the open unit disk onto a region $U$ if and only if $U$ is simply connected and the complement of $U$ (in the Riemann sphere) has at least two points.

The Möbius transformation $w=\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ maps the left side into the unit disk, but it doesn't satisfy that property. I tried some other forms of the bilinear transformation without any luck, and I suspect that such transformation may not exist. Is my suspicion correct?

Comment: Is it $w_1=f(z_1), w_2=f(z_2)$?

Comment: @edm isn't that obvious? Should I explicitly say it?

Comment: It is not obvious at all. The symbols are undefined.

Answer (score 2):

In the title you didn't say 'onto' but in the question you have put this extra condition. Since $f$ is onto there exists $z_2$ such that $w_2=f(z_2)=0$. But then $|z_1|<|z_2|$ implies $|w_1|<0$, a contradiction.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Please ignore my abuse of words. The condition restricts $f$ to the ones that $f(0)=0$ and I don't see any contradiction

Comment: @polfosol 0 is not in the domain of the function (left half plane)...

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki does it make any difference if I change the domain to _left half of the plane including the imaginary axis_?

Comment: @polfosol kind of, because what's a holomorphic function on a set that is not open? but I suspect that in any case there are no such functions even without any condition like onto or $f(0)=0$

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki I suspected that too. But I am not sure yet